# Relation in one table

Tags: php, laravel

I have table books (model `Book`) with columns: `id`, `group_key`, `content`. And I have 3 rows in this table:

```
1 | 1 | content1
2 | 1 | content2
3 | 1 | content3;
```

In model I have relation

```
public function allGroupItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'group_key');
}
```

I get first item in table and try to use relation `allGroupItems` to get all rows in table with the same `group_key` as in first item.

```
$book = Book::find(1);
dd($book->allGroupItems); // 3 rows
```

And I succeed. I'm getting 3 rows as expected. But if I try to do the same with second or third row, I'v got empty array as result:

```
$book = Book::find(2);
dd($book->allGroupItems); // empty array
```

I expect to get the same 3 rows. I don't understand why I am getting an empty array. What's wrong?

Laravel 9.52.7, php 8.2.1

Comment: Your relation is not defined ok. Use twice the group_key. 1st case is coincidence.

Comment: @marius-ciclistu could you give an example, please?

Comment: public function allGroupItems(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'group_key', 'group_key');
}

Comment: @marius-ciclistu it works. please make answer, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function allGroupItems(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'group_key', 'group_key');
}
```